# How do I check if a Youtube Video is Embeddable?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, youtube

Im developing an app that will playback youtube videos IF the video is embeddable. Else I want to open it in Youtube.

My code for it looks like this:

```
holder.mThumbnailImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Playback in mobile

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(holder.mContext, YouTubePlayerFragmentActivity.class);
            sendIntent.putExtra("id", video.getId());
            holder.mContext.startActivity(sendIntent);

            // BELOW IS WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN IF THE VIDEO IS NOT EMBEDDALBE
            // 
            // holder.mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video.getId())));

        }
    });
```

Can someone help me out? Do I need to provide more code for you to understand?

Thx

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). Apparently the YouTube Data API allows you to get information about a video. The returned data will have a key named "videoEmbeddable". I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can you help me with the next task?

The Way I see it I can put 

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&maxResults=1&q={vide.getID())}&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true&videoSyndicated=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

To get the return. Then I need to figure out what I should replace {vide.getID())} in the above code with, and also how to check if it gives me a return or error. 

I'm thinking like: If above GET returns a value Do task 1. Else Do task 2.

What do you think?

Comment: I'll look into it a bit more. There may be a better way of doing it. (hopefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally, finally figured out how to do this properly!

To get this information, make a HTTP `GET` request with your API key and the video Id to the YouTube Data API v3:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=<VIDEO ID>&key=<YOUR API KEY>&part=status`

[EDIT] **How to check if a video is embeddable using the YouTube Data API v3 from android using HTTP requests**

**Step 1:**
 First things first, you have to configure your project to use the Volley API. We will be using this library to send and receive HTTP requests. Open your `build.gradle` file and paste the link:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

**Step 2:**
Open up your activity file where you want to make the request from. Add the following variables:

```
String url_pre = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=";
String url_mid = "&key=";
String url_suf = "&part=status";
String video_id = "4pTwQKMrTt0"; //set this string be the id of your video
final String API_KEY = "your-api-key";

RequestQueue queue;
```

**Step 3:**
If you haven't made an API key for your project yet, head over to the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/) to generate one. Also add `android.permission.INTERNET` to your android manifest permissions.

**Step 4:**
Now we have to initialize our `RequestQueue` and setup our JSON Object Request:

```
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_pre + video_id + url_mid + API_KEY + url_suf, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject videoItem = (JSONObject) response.getJSONArray("items").get(0);
                JSONObject status = videoItem.getJSONObject("status");
                boolean isVideoEmbeddable = status.getBoolean("embeddable");
                //isVideoEmbeddable will be equal to true if the video is embeddable, and false if it isn't.
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("My Class", "Volley Error: ",error);
    }
});
queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: Been scratching my head so much but can´t still figure it out. Did´nt want to ask to much either because trainning makes perfect. haha.

But i need to know how to make the Http Get and how to parse it using Json.

Comment: I'll look into it this evening (in 11 hours approx) I'm happy to help :)

Comment: Awesome! Your the best! :)

Comment: Thanks for another good answer. Took me quite far :) BUT I get red underlineing on "response.getJSONArray("items")" and it says "Array Type expected". Also Im not sure about the Singleton part on the end. 

I guess my action after this will be something like "if isEmbeddable = "true"; { do stuff} right? 

Can you please help me understand the Mysingleton part? :)

Comment: Yes, that last part is right. I have also updated my code so that you don't need the singleton anymore. I will look into the JSON bug tomorrow.

Comment: You have saved me man! IT WORKS PERFECTLY!! :D 

Just had to change "this" as context on the Volley object to "view.getContext()" since I am in a fragment :)